# How can I use the EV3 educational firmware instead of the retail version?

Tags: ev3, software, education

I have an EV3 brick from the retail kit, which is currently running the retail firmware. I would like to replace the EV3's firmware with the educational version. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** LEGO Education software is now available for free.

https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3

Original answer:

You need to purchase the EV3 Education version of the software. It includes the EV3 Education version firmware.

- [EV3 Education Software (single user licence)](http://education.lego.com/en-us/lego-education-product-database/mindstorms-ev3/2000045-lego-mindstorms-education-ev3-software-single-user)
- [EV3 Software v1.1 Update (includes v1.06E firmware update)](http://education.lego.com/en-us/preschool-and-school/secondary/mindstorms-education-ev3/support/ev3-software-update)